# Как отправить моносообщение(сообщение которое можно копировать при нажатии) в телеграм через бота в PHP?

Tags: php

[image: Вот]

Нужно что бы номер был как сообщение которое можно сразу скопировать кликом, слышал что просто сообщение отправленное через "`", но тут он ставиться как текст, а не преобразовывается в оформление текста как моно

Answer (score 0):

Нужно не только текст обернуть в обратные кавычки, но и сказать, что это MARKDOWN текст

Например:

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Обычный текст `Копируемый текст` ', parse_mode="MARKDOWN")
```